# corrected projections: Is this world map realistic? I tried to use plate tectonics to inform my mountain and island chain placements

Tags: planets, earth-like, geography, map-making, tectonics

[image: jasmi satellite equirectangular]
[image: jasmi heightmap equirectangular]

1 degree of latitude = 96.57 km.

Equirectangular projections. (Yes, I need to revise the polar regions to make sure they don't get squished.)

Obliquity of Jasmi: +31.1 degrees.

Radius of Jasmi: 0.87 R<sub>Earth</sub>

Marked (too vaguely, I know,) are the equator, 31.1 degrees, 40 degrees and 58.9 degrees (my tropical and polar circles, as well as my subtropic/temperate regions).

Disregard the colors on the top map if you like; in a previous iteration of my planet's flora evolutionary timeline, I made this map to highlight diverse species of algae blooms around my continents.

Lighter color = higher elevation in the second map

Thanks!
<3 R

Comment: Without seeing the sea-floor and some elevation data any answer I could give would be a guess.

Comment: @Ash I tried to indicate where the mountains would be, but I honestly don't know where to begin with realistic elevation data. My planetary radius is 0.870 R(earth), and my mass is 0.602 M(earth) if that helps at all.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to imply hard altitude data, but relative elevations tell you a lot about the tectonic and geological systems that underpin a map. The seafloor tells you more about tectonic structure than the land too.

Comment: You will have to show us the actual plate boundaries. Without showing us the plate boundaries, the answer-er will have to make them up by themselves. That means that each answer can have its own imagined plate boundaries, so the answers will be 'primarily opinion based.' I'm going to say that it looks good to me, but I will vote to close this question as opinion based.

Comment: Have you seen this? It may help: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2594/creating-a-realistic-world-series

Comment: @kingledion fair enough; I will submit a new map with plate boundaries once I translate the ones I drew on paper into GIMP 2.

Comment: @TimB thank you so much! It's very helpful to have that all in one place. I'll give it a look.

Comment: Is this "world" map of the whole planet or just a particular section?

Comment: @LioElbammalf this is the entire planet

Comment: Please provide necessary info to interpret the maps such as: Projection, lines marking regular intervals of longitude/latitude with degrees marked on them, legends for the colours used (while you tell us to disregard colours in the former map, the latter map shows gradients between white and black, yet without knowing which colour is which extreme the heightmap cannot be interpreted (well it can in that case as we can deduce that lighter must mean higher up due to landmasses being white-ish - but it's in general good practice to always add a legend for such maps))

Comment: @dot_Sp0T understood! I will edit that info in now. Thank you!

Comment: I like this. If I find the time I will produce some maps with your picture, showing you some planar and geographic projections on an auxiliary sphere and how your planet looks like in those. You'll be surprised...

Comment: but, see Lio's answer. and my comment. or else...,)

Comment: That's a lot of water compared to the amount of land.  This world would experience really bad storms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your surface is too small

Radius is given as $0.87 R_{Earth}$, so we expect an equatorial circumference of $0.87\times2\pi  R_{Earth}=34826km$

Boston to LA is [2992 Miles](https://www.distance-cities.com/distance-boston-ma-to-los-angeles-ca) (4815.2 km), your equatorial continent fits about five times into the map you've provided giving us only **24076km**.

So **your map is missing about ten thousand kilometers of space** for the size planet you wanted.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like my BOTE calculation failed me. Would you suggest adding more space in the map, or just re-calculating the size of that one continent? It occurs to me that the dimensions of my map are probably not ideal for an equirectangular projection. I'm very new to mapmaking.

Comment: It really depends on what you want the world for. At first glance this was all I could see that was wrong with it.

Comment: both I'd say...first off, an equiectangular map, naturally, needs a 2:1 size ratio to make sense. there's a catch though, as with all map projections: this one distorts distances (e.g. google/openstreetmap distorts area), to a significant higher degree with higher your latitudes (if you draw a circle on the map and two radius lines at 90° and 180°, actual length in map units for the latter will be *roughly* 1.4 times longer). areal distortion, however, will be much more abstract to design I think (the northern continent would roughly be half the size/area than it appears on the map)

Comment: @t.ry I have added more area to the map to make the projection make sense!

Answer (score 0):

If your planet's orbit parameters are anything like Earth's there would supposedly be some ice sheets on the poles.
*Update: Ice is not necessary, as mentioned in the comments below. Maybe a nice to have though, don´t know if that would actually fit your story.*
Maybe even land due to [equatorial buldge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equatorial_bulge) (I refer specifically to the water mass...theres lot's of oceans to buldge there, and much space at the equator to flow to).
I could also imagine massive global storms and extremely strong circumpolar currents as a result.
This is what I could do with both your maps:

- heights are scaled to -7000m and 6000m (i.e. roughly two thirds of
  Earth's    min/max)
- I georeferenced both pictures onto a sphere according to your planet's size and used a modified [Robinson projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_projection) for this

- derived height map:
  [image: behold...your height map]
  Note: according to your picture, significant parts of your ocean would be higher than the continents...
- mashup, color relief and superimposed world image:
  [image: behold...your world!]
  Note: colors don't really make sense, but with that elevation model I couldn´t help it. The landmasses are more or less uniform and mostly level with the surrounding ocean (at 2000m...), so the shaded relief has not much effect here

But it looks quite good. Not too bad at least. I had no time for magic...
Also, I´m not sure if this does have anything to do with the question...but: maps.

Comment: Polar ice isn't a necessity. During the Cretaceous, Earth didn't have permanent polar ice caps. There's some data suggesting that in the Arctic and Antarctic regions there may have only been persistent ice in areas 1000+ meters above sea level.

Comment: We are currently in an 'ice age'. For most of Earth's history there were not permanent ice caps. The current ice age started about 33 million years ago, when Antarctica was isolated, and the Antarctic ice cap formed. Before then, there was no permanent ice cap for hundreds of millions of years. There may be some connection with continental position and ice cap formation. Since the OP's map does not have a polar continent, it may not have ice caps either.